# Microsoft Graph. How I can access information in a scope for empId Attribue with the scope that doesn't require admin consent

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph in my ASP.NET MVC app and trying to get some users data. I am facing two issue as following:

I want to achieve is too remove the paging, if this is possible. The data for users is < 18,000 but all the information I need it is name and the email. Currently I only get first 100 records. In order to get all I just added 18000 which should bring all the records that exists right now. I failed and got a 403 error. But what is actually I want to be able to get all the records without having to type $top=xxxxx.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=18000&$select=displyaname,email";](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=18000&$select=displyaname,email%22;)

This returns an 403 error

Comment: have some mercy why -2?

Comment: If a scope requires consent, you cannot bypass that. Image the security nightmare if I could just bypass authorization because I want a piece of information. IMHO option your question was downvoted because you did not show what you tried, what the error was, and a clear description of the problem. I would delete the question, do more research, write a clear software development question with code, errors, stack traces, etc and post a new question. This link should help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks I did dig little bit more and I am going to rewrite my question. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graph explorer to test this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

"top" needs to be 999 or less. Not specifying should return all by default.Your displayName is also spelled incorrectly. If you're using default attibutes, it should be "mail" and not "email"

Please let me know if this works. Try this: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,mail

Comment: thanks for your help and reply.  I tried the endpoint to select the displayname and mail.  I got the total set 100.     RequestMessage = {Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,mail',   and in response i noticed odata.nextLink":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName%2cmail.....   So if by default if it brings all the records then why woud it sent the response with nextLink?

Answer (score 0):

I used the client credential flow to avoid getting the consent approach.  In this approach, consent was done by the admin on the Azure portal.

For the numbers of records, by default I was getting 100 records each time.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging